# There is no file with ID 1. The file list may have changed

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I have this in my razor.component file

```
<MudFileUpload T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>"
                   FilesChanged="InsertFiles"
                   Accept=".jpg, .png, .bmp"
                   Style="display:contents">
</MudFileUpload>

<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled"
           EndIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Send"
           Color="Color.Primary"
           FullWidth="true"
           ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"
           Class="btn-user ml-4"
           Disabled="@buttonDisabled">
       Submit
</MudButton>
```

If I select multiple items all at the same time and "submit", I do not get any errors up to my API. But if I select 1 file at a time, then I get an error of

> There is no file with ID 1. The file list may have changed.

during "submit".

Putting it into context, if I use a PC, I can just drag my mouse to files I need and just click on the "open" button. But if I am using a phone, I cannot select multiple items at the same time, I would need to select 1 file at a time and click the open button to add it to the list I need to upload. But as I have mentioned, If I click one file then open it, then, click on the file input button again and select another file, my list actually grows from 1 file to 2 files then 3 files and so on. But when I click on the "submit" button, that's the time I get an error. If I just select 1 file or mutiple files at once then "submit", I do not get any issues. Please see my component.razor.cs

```
private IList<IBrowserFile> files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
private void InsertFiles(IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files)
{
    var fileSize = 0f;
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        fileSize = totalFileSize + item.Size;
        this.files.Add(item);
    }
}

private async Task SubmitAsync()
{
    try
    {
        using var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        foreach (var file in this.files)
        {
            var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize));
            fileContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(file.ContentType);

            content.Add(
            content: fileContent,
            name: "\"files\"",
            fileName: file.Name);
        }
        
        var response = await mHttpService!.Post<List<UploadResult>>("api/some-end-point", content);
        
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        mSnackbar!.Add($@"Exception ecountered: {e.Message}", Severity.Error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem exists also with the Blazor built-in InputFile component.
It's caused by the limitation of the HTML file input on which it's based. Every time the input is activated by clicking or drag-and-drop, its file list is reset, so the items in your IBrowserFile list lose their reference.
The solution (which I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77513749/1531760)) is to hide the active InputFile after each selection and create another one which will be activated on the next click or drag-and-drop.

I tested the same method on the MudFileUpload component, and it works as well.
Here are the relevant parts of your code with the necessary additions:

```
    @for (int i = 0; i <= currentFileSelection; i++) { 
        <MudFileUpload T="IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile>"
                       FilesChanged="InsertFiles"
                       Accept=".jpg, .png, .bmp"
                       Style="display:contents"
                       Hidden="i != currentFileSelection">
        </MudFileUpload>
    }
```

...

```
private IList<IBrowserFile> files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
int currentFileSelection = 0;
private void InsertFiles(IReadOnlyList<IBrowserFile> files)
{
    var fileSize = 0f;
    foreach (var item in files)
    {
        fileSize = totalFileSize + item.Size;
        this.files.Add(item);
    }
    currentFileSelection++;
}
```